# Custom title bar in PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, titlebar

I am using a custom title bar for my all activities but i can use this in PreferenceActivity.
All i can do in PreferenceActivity is this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences3);
```

My title bar in preference activity stay always grey without any text but other activities works very well this code. What i can do to solve my problem??

Comment: and if you find it helpful accept answer to help everybody..

Answer (score 3):

put `getWindow()....` after super and `addPreferencesFromResource...` so order should be:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences3);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
```

p.s. credits to original author [@jeffrey-blattman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337455/jeffrey-blattman) following [my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935596/304270)..