# How can I show title in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferences

I use `PreferenceActivity` as well as in this example for Tablets [Android from 4.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

But it does not display the title in the header, how can these ads?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831325/custom-title-of-preferenceactivity-problem

Comment: The anser is to add the ActionBar!  Thanx all for Help!!

Comment: pleas post you answer and accept it so that it can help other people in future...

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause ttitle is not enabled.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Change it to and then call `setTitle()`

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
setTitle("Your Title");
```